# Adding to a dictionary c#

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains classes. However, I have a lot of classes to add to the dictionary and I would like to eliminate the long list of adds, because it's starting to look messy. I was thinking of having all the data in a file and loading it to add to the dictionary, but then I realized that every time I wanted to create and add a new class, I would have to modify the file. I would prefer to have to include something in my newly created class that would automatically add it to the dictionary. I'm not even sure this is possible, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: When you say that the dictionary contains classes, do you mean that it contains `Type` objects for classes, or instances of classes?

Comment: Sql is not an option and it contains Type objects for classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use reflection to dynamically locate all the required classes. Create an instance of `Assembly` where your classes are defined and try to filter them out. An example below shows how to locate all the classes whose name ends with `Task`.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var taskTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Task") && t.IsClass);

Dictionary<string, object> instances =
    new Dictionary<string, object>(taskTypes.Count());

foreach (Type classType in taskTypes)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
    instances.Add(classType.Name, instance);
    Console.WriteLine("Registered key {0} with object of type {1})",
                      classType.Name,
                      instance);
}
```

I've used `Activator.CreateInstance` method to create instances of your classes, but this might not be possible in your case depending on whether they have parameterless contructors etc.

Another option might be to use one of the available IoC containers like [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) but I need more details on your problem before I can give a proper advice on this.

Comment: This is perfect, but what if instead of adding all classes that ended with a common name, I could add all classes that derive from a certain class. Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? I've posted a complete example [here](http://codepaste.net/y7jh82) - hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will make the necessary changes to be able to use `Activator.CreateInstance`

Answer (score 0):

Make the dictionary a static field of some class, or make the "add class to dictionary" a static method.

Then, you can use a *static constructor* to add each class to the dictionary:

```
class ClassDict {
    ...
    public static void AddClass(Type t) {
        ...
    }
}

class Foo {
    static Foo() {
        ClassDict.AddClass(typeof(Foo));
    }
}
```